# KStream-KStream-Join with different Results on consecutive executions

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

Because I don't know whether my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318358/kstream-kstream-join-less-resulting-records-than-expected) will be reopened.. here a more precise question.

I have StreamA (containing a product which is produced within a 30 minutes interval) and StreamB (containing measurements from 4 different sensors, producing a measurement every 5 minutes each). These two streams are joined on a common key. StreamC is the result of this join and contains measurementEnrichedProducts.

I have ~15k products and ~250k measurements. Below are the results:

---

```
Run   Num records within StreamC
1     149,389
2     149,362
3     149,363
4     149,411
```

Each run had the exact same config and the events in streamA/B were the same too.

I really do not know why this is the case. Is it possible that there are any problems with the underlying statestores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was restarting the application too fast...

When playing with the [max.task.idle.ms-property](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#max-task-idle-ms) I noticed that the results were stable (same amount every execution) but less than before. After letting the application run for more than 15 minutes (max.task.idle.ms=600000[10minutes]) I received some more results and the number of records in streamC were stable too.

Removing *max.task.idle.ms* again and waiting long enough lead to the same results.

I suspect the problem occurred due to the out-of-order input data and internal buffers not being filled.